# Write an Entire Array with a Single Write

Tags: arrays, vbscript

This may be a very trivial question, but I cannot seem to find the answer on Google.

Is there a way to write an entire array of strings to a file without having to loop through the array in VBScript?

Comment: What is in the Array? Have you tried `Join`?

Comment: It's an array of strings, I have not tried Join. I will look into what the function does. (I am not very comfortable with vbscript)

Comment: Why do you want to serialize array without looping? Is it for performance reason only? or something else? I wonder whether Join may be internally using a loop to generate its output. Does it even perform better than a loop?

Comment: @rineez It did not perform better than the loop. It is for performance. I have a file that I have to read in, edit a line at the bottom, and print back to the file. The file is 90,000 lines long.

Comment: That sounds like a huge array. In that case I think Join in to string and then writing to file may actually run slower than just reading array and writing to file in a same loop. You should probably rethink and consider doing it differently than trying to make it faster.

Comment: For example: you are reading a huge file just to read and edit one line. May be you could split your array in to a few smaller parts and write them in to multiple files so that you have to read/write only smaller files. Of course, the file name should follow some convention to easily locate the file containing relevant part of array that is to be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim aData 
    aData = Array( "a", "b", "c", "d" )

With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("file.txt", True)
    .Write Join(aData, vbCrLf)
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: This works in a general sense, however, is really slow with large arrays. I will mark it as the answer as it would be useful in a general case.

Comment: @user2970916, The code answers the original question. BUT for a big array there are a lot of concatenations to do in memory, maybe the problem is not the write operation but the array usage. As rineez points a different approach could lead to a faster solution.